# Compare href with window.location.hash on click, add class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a script that compares the `href` value inside the clicked `li` with `window.location.hash`, and if they match, add a class to the clicked `li`. In other words, I'm styling an active nav section. It almost works–if the `href` and `window.location.hash` match, it only adds the class the second time the `li` is clicked. I'm assuming it's an event issue. I tried adding a timeout, but that didn't work.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
$('#left-nav > ul > li').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).find('.left-nav-link').attr('href') == window.location.hash) {
    $('#left-nav > ul > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

HTML structure:

```
<div id="left-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="left-nav-link" href="#first-link">First Link</a></li>
    <li><a class="left-nav-link" href="#second-link">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a class="left-nav-link" href="#third-link">Third Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `alert($(this).find('.left-nav-link').attr('href') + " == " + window.location.hash);` might be informative.

Comment: Can you add the html implied please? That way we can help you

Comment: @JulioPérez Sure, just added

Comment: Why do you need the `if()` when you already know which element was clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems over complicated. You don't need the `if()` since you already know which element was clicked

```
$('#left-nav > ul > li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');   
});
```

Comment: Good point. I think I left the `if ()` from a different approach I tried. This works!

Comment: @MarioParra It's a matter of event triggering/timing, you were checking to see if they match before the hash changes, that's why it always worked on the second click

Comment: @Curt Yeah, I understood that, that's why I tried adding a delay/timeout to check after it changes, but it didn't work and I didn't know what else to try.

Comment: @Curt think so too...a setTimeout would have probably fixed it but still overkill for the situation

Comment: If you had multiple anchor elements to the same hash URL, you could always bind the check to window.onhashchange instead of the click of the LI element, then you would need the === check